# How can i do one continuous tap across widgets and do some action when widget touch like piano one touch across piano keys?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, mobile-application

How can i do one continuous tap across widgets and do some action when widget touch like piano one touch across piano keys make its tone?

Answer (score 0):

1. Wrap all widgets ("piano keys") in GestureDetector.
2. Subscribe to onPanStart/onPanUpdate events.
3. Both events expose pointer location, so that you can use it to calculate what widget is below pointer. Assumption is that your know or can easily calculate your widget sizes.